# Motion Blur Render Time

Tags: rendering, animation, motion-blur

I am rendering a pretty simple animation using Cycles. I render with my GPU, not CPU, and it's pretty nice. I have, however, encountered a problem.

If I turn on **Motion Blur**, frame takes half of forever to render and crashes my GPU.

If I turn off **Motion Blur** render is really quick. Is there a way to make it render faster? I would prefer not to use compositor to add the motion blur.

[image: RenderSettings1]

[image: RenderSettings2]

[image: RenderSettings3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but there's no way to make motion blur rendering in cycles any faster for now. [how blender developers made motion blur 10x faster](https://cloud.blender.org/blog/cycles-turbocharged-how-we-made-rendering-10x-faster)

As you can see in the article that they have already improved and sped up motion blur rendering by a lot. Compositing is your only choice left if you want it fast.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this post is a few years old, but this is one of the first things that comes up on Google when you search for this issue and perhaps my experience will help some passersby.

I recently ran into a situation where I was animating a plesiosaur in Cycles at about 16 samples with motion blur turned on. It was taking between 2 and 10 minutes per frame (depending on how dramatic the frame-to-frame movement was).

On the very last frame, the estimate suddenly jumped up to 7 hours, with no discernible reason as to why. However, upon further inspection, it suddenly became clear that I had made a frame AFTER the last frame... wherein the plesiosaur was in an extremely different position. In other words, the motion was no longer continuous, so Blender was calculating overtime to try and figure out how to render such an insane motion blur.

Bottom line, if anyone does run into this issue, try to make sure none of your objects suddenly have an extremely dramatic frame-to-frame movement, because that can slow things down to a snail's crawl when motion blur is turned on. The more continuous your motion, the better. Hope this helps any passersby! Peace and God bless!